# Grep issues: Why is grep -i not grabbing the instance with special characters

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to find this:

```
gxxcc/issdd/jaabb/krrss/lxxnn
```

On this (all capital letters)

```
AXXRR/BVVTTS/CRRTTDD/DEETTFF/EAABBRR/FRSSTT/GXXCC/ISSDD/JAABB_KRRSS_LXXNN/LL
```

I tried this

```
grep -i 'GXXCC/ISSDD/JAABB.KRRSS.LXXNN' filename.txt 
grep -i 'GXXCC*ISSDD*JAABB*KRRSS*LXXNN' filename.txt
```

but, neither of those  work. Any solution and explanation?

Comment: `echo A/B/C/D/E/F/G/I/J_K_L/LL | grep -i 'G/I/J.K.L'` works just fine. It seems that you oversimplified the example

Comment: I added some strings to see if this helps

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine

Comment: So, suggestions why i do have that problem?

Comment: Works fine for me, too, so more information is needed. What unix/linux version, grep version, shell (and version), etc are you using? Something must be wrong if it isn't working, and it isn't the syntax. Also, do you have grep aliased to anything in your shell rc file?

Comment: With `grep -Fi` I don't have any hits. Does `grep -Ei` help you?

Answer (score 0):

This, from your example, works fine, highlighting a portion of the text:

```
echo AXXRR/BVVTTS/CRRTTDD/DEETTFF/EAABBRR/FRSSTT/GXXCC/ISSDD/JAABB_KRRSS_LXXNN/LL |
  egrep -i --color 'gxxcc/issdd/jaabb.krrss.lxxnn'
```

Avoid patterns like `D*JAABB*K`. That would match text like 'JAABBBBBBK' or 'DDDDDJAABK', rather than slashes or underscores.

The `.` dot matches exactly one character. Is your `_` underscore maybe some crazy utf8 multibyte sequence, rather than ascii 95? One way to tell is to put Kleene stars in your pattern: `egrep -i --color 'jaabb.*krrss.*lxxnn'`. Another is to view your text with `hexdump -C`

Comment: yes, that was a crazy multibit. Thanks for the input